# how do you do a class connection  to connect to a remote database?

Tags: c#, .net, connection, database-connection, connection-string

I have a class connection, but it doesn't work. It does work in the same network (intranet), but it doesn't work over the internet.

It is a SQL Server - i have a user, a pass- and this privated ip, public ip is 189.148.67.149

I had configured SQL Server to accept tcp/ip, but the application doesn't work:

> Error related to the specific network or of the instance while a connection with servant SQL Server settled down. Was not the servant or this one was not accessible. It verifies that the name of the instance is correct and that SQL Server is formed to admit remote connections. (to provider: Supplier of TCP, error: 0 - An error took place during the attempt of connection since the connected part did not respond suitably after a period of time, or an error in the established connection took place since host connected has not been able to respond.)

I tranlated that with in http://es.babelfish.yahoo.com/translate_txt in spanish (my languaje)

> Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Proveedor de TCP, error: 0 - Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder.)

```
class Conexion
{
     public SqlConnection conectar()
    {
        //my pc is called alumno-auc
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.82,1433;Initial Catalog=misnotas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=login2; Password=login2; Asynchronous Processing=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Network Library=dbmssocn;Workstation ID=alumno-auc;User Instance=False"); 
        return con;
    }

    public void EjecutarConsulta(SqlCommand comando)
    {
        comando.Connection.Open(); // abrimos la conexion
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery(); // ejecutamos la consulta
        comando.Connection.Close(); // y cerramos la conexion
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a "red" that it does work in?

Comment: Can you connect to it via SQL Server Tools like management studio or SQL CMD? I suspect this is a infrastructural/networking issue.

Comment: @Preet i do have a connection since the same computer, and i do have a connection since other computer (in the same network(intranet)) but i dont have a connection since internet (since your house for example)

Comment: "It verifies that the name of the instance is correct" - Buffalo Bill is writing SQL Server dialog boxes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a firewall between the server and the public Internet? Do you have to change a firewall rule or port forwarding to allow public access?  Do you have a software firewall running on the machine? See http://www.sevenforums.com/system-security/58817-remote-access-sql-server-express-2008-windows-7-a.html for info about Windows Firewall in Windows 7 for Sql express.

This troubleshooting guide should be helpful - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Are you sure you want your SQL server on the public Internet? You've really got to know how to manage your security if you are doing this. It is usually not recommended.

I attempted to attach to your server using the info you've supplied, I got the following error from SQL Server Management Studio 2008:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to 189.148.67.149.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: i know, i can't connect, do you know if sql express 2008 can allow remote connection?

Comment: See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sqlnetfx/thread/3ef2f872-c978-4eb0-bd27-b13b3544ac4c and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities here.

1. The SQL Server port  is not open on the server in question.
2. The SQL Server instances uses a non-standard port.
3. The SQL Server instance does not have SQL Browser service on, so it does not accept remote connections.
4. You have the wrong protocol to connect.

I am sure I can think of others given a bit more time.

Comment: i do accept remote connection, port is 1433, i am sure it must to work, but it doesn't do, as i write in description, it does work in intranet but it doesn't work in internet, it does work with privated ip, but it doesn't work (in the same intranet) with public ip

Answer (score 1):

An original English exception message can be found at [www.unlocalize.com](http://www.unlocalize.com/es/35557_A-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-SQL-Server.html) as well as several links to existing solutions.